# 404 page not found error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to the codeigniter framework and I have tried to make my first program but received a  `404 page not found` error

This is my root directory `Codeigniter` and my directory structure

[image]

My source folder contains the .htaccess file containing the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Home.php

```
    class  Home extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('View');
    }
}
```

view.php

```
echo "HI this is my first codeigniter program";
```

I have tried the following url `http://localhost/Codeigniter/` but I 
get a 404 error, however `http://localhost/Codeigniter/home` loads the correct result even though  my actual root folder is Codeigniter

how to solve this problem?

Comment: try this http://localhost/Codeigniter/index.php/home   ?

Comment: check the default controller in route file 
CodeIgniter/application/config/routes.php

Comment: Thank you Rajkumar.. after i changed `$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';` it has worked correct..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change route file in this following path:-

```
CodeIgniter/application/config/routes.php

$route['default_controller'] = 'required_controller';
```

Then only you can access the following url

```
http://localhost/Codeigniter/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try where

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

change to

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Or

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

More htaccess [here](https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter)

Make sure your htaccess is outside of application folder.

And then on config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/'; 

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And then you can set your routes.php lower case best on routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```