# 404/net::ERR_ABORTED error for assets in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I'm working through my first Codeigniter webpage, and I've run into a few peculiarities. The first is that I haven't needed to use base_url or site_url in front of my URLs to get them to work, at least not originally. I set up the main page, and simply did

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and this seemed to automatically add the domain name in front of it. I'm not sure how it worked, but it works for all the URLs like it. When I look at the inspect window, it shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dNJa.jpg). I don't know if this is relevant, but I wanted to make note of it.

The issue was on my second page. I added a new controller named Admin, and set it to bring up a different page. I set up the URLs in the same way I did before, but when I loaded it, the CSS and Javascript didn't load. In case it matters, I tried loading it by doing Domainname.com/Admin. The html loads correctly, but when I looked at the console, it gave me a [net::ERR_ABORTED and 404 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIwxV.jpg) for my images and files. I've double checked all of them, and they are all in the correct spot. I found this page: [404 page not found error in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787790/404-page-not-found-error-in-codeigniter) and tried using the solution there in my .htaccess file. It not only didn't work, but now the original page that was working correctly refuses to load up any of the asset files. I tried removing the new line of code, but it still will not work correctly, even though everything is the exact same way it was before.

Here is my .htaccess folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /eventCentral/

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d

#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)

RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I tried removing the commented piece of code completely, but it still didn't fix it.

My file structure is also correct, and can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCNl3.jpg).

As I said, I'm still very new to code igniter, so if answers can be broken down Barney style, I'd appreciate it. I've also tried looking through a number of stack overflow questions that seemed relevant, and I still haven't found a solution that works.

Comment: Make sure you have set your base url in config,php and try `href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>"` make sure you have loaded the url helper or autoload the url helper

Comment: No dice. Still didn't work. It actually goes weird when I do that. It tries to go to http://www.domainname.com/www.domainname.com/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css

I figured that out early, and why I don't use base_url or site_url. It just goes weird for some reason. It does that every time i add the base_url or site_url in front of any of the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use the URL helper's functions, but unless you prefix your URLs with a forward slash, the BROWSER decides that your asset is actually prefixed with the URI segments from the current page. That's because the browser sees the URL as a relative URL. In order to overcome that, either use the forward slash, or a base tag: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Example of base tag:

```
<base href="https://example.com/">
```

In my own applications, I just make my URLs absolute with the forward slash prefix. In your case that would look like this:

```
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

EDIT ----

I just noticed that your htaccess has 2 lines, and I'd like you to convert the parens to curly braces, so:

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
```

Should be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Just for kicks, try to change this:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

To this:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but it still does the weird double domain thing.  
It tries to go to domainname.com/www.domainname.com/assets/css/bootstrap.min.c‌​ss

Edit: Nevermind, I misread the post. It doesn't do the double domain thing, but it still doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Maybe you've not configured your application correctly? That's not normal behaviour for a browser. With the exception of your rewrite base, all the code you have shown looks normal.

Comment: I've gone through the configuration folder with a fine toothed comb. The only things I've changed are the base_url and the error logging, which shows ERROR - 2017-12-24 19:09:33 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/js for all the URLs that try to access the Assets folder.

Comment: If you'd create a minimal example of the output HTML and add it to your question, it would be beneficial. I've got to leave for a couple hours, but will check back then.

Comment: Apparently it was just the curly braces. I guess when I was watching the tutorial video, I misread that part of the code. Thanks for your help @BrianGottier

Comment: Your welcome. If marking this answer as the accepted answer is appropriate, I'd appreciate if you would do that. Have a great night.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|assets|myadmin|robots.txt)

Comment: i find solution add this line